# No. of ways a specific outcome can occur when 12 die are thrown simultaneously

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Twelve normal and fair dice are thrown once. What is the total number of ways in which each of the values $1,2,3,4,5,6$ occur exactly twice? e.g. $(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)$

My attempt:

The above problem would be similar to the to the number of arrangements of $12$ digits $(1,6)$ out of which each digit is repeated twice… and hence the number of ways the above outcome can occur will be equal to $\frac{12!}{6!}$.

But it seems that my answer is wrong; the answer key reports the answer to be $\frac{12!}{2^6}$.

Is my approach to the problem incorrect? If so, then could you please suggest a way to solve the problem?

Comment: Exactly one pair and the other 9 dice without pairs i.e. $(1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)$ is an outcome and $(1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6)$ isn't counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways it can occur is going to be the [Multinomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2} = \frac{12!}{2!2!2!2!2!2!}$

A way in which you can see this without using multiniomial coefficients directly (*but is equivalent to, it is afterall how they were developed*) is to approach via multiplication principle with the following steps:

- Pick the location of the two $1$'s:  $\binom{12}{2}$ ways
- From the remaining locations, pick the location of the two $2$'s: $\binom{10}{2}$ ways
- From the remaining locations, pick the location of the two $3$'s: $\binom{8}{2}$ ways

  $\vdots$
- From the remaining locations pick the location of the two $6$'s: $\binom{2}{2}$ ways

multiplying these together gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

If we were considering permutations of $12$ distinct numbers, there would be $12!$ permutations,
but each number is repeated twice, so we need to divide by $2!$ for each such occurrence,
thus $\dfrac{12!}{2!2!2!2!2!2!} = \dfrac{12!}{2^6}$

Comment: Alright...thanks!! My mistake was to assume that there are two sets each of 6 similar objects and hence i divided it by 6! but actually its vice versa....anyways....thanks for helping me out guys!!

Comment: You're welcome !